# How to sort split group of metric visualization?

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

Is there a way to sort the given metrics descending?

[image: Metric split group]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official support at kibana forums:

Unfortunately, there's no way to sort filters aggregation. However, depending on how complicated your filters are, you might be able to create a terms aggregation and add filters to the whole visualization, eg. on the enclosed picture I filter to only get destination (Dest) of the three airports I am interested in and sort it by descending order.

[image]